# Error in tapply(y, by, sum) : total number of levels >= 2^31

Tags: r, data-processing

I get the main idea behind this error, my data is too big 512218 records with 3 variables and I'm trying to convert the dataframe to tabular format so I can get adjacency matrix. Right now I'm using xtabs and getting this error

```
n <- xtabs(USER_LINK ~ screenName + screen_name_mention, df)
```

I tried using `sapply(df,table)` (as mentioned in a related question) but it didn't work. What I want to know is there an alternative way to convert dataframe to tabular format without getting this error?

`head` of data

```
 screenName    screen_name_mention   USER_LINK
1  g_fandos       ecolandlab            1
2 andrewmbrass    PLOSBiology           1
3 andrewmbrass    PLOSBiology           1
4  welloldstem     dbcurren             1
5 PaulJDavison     BehavEcol            1
6  cbjones1943     BiolJLinnSocÂ¿       1
```

str(df)

```
'data.frame':   512218 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ screenName         : Factor w/ 150233 levels "","#$%","#cuttingeeg",..: 50920 8866 8866 145600 106833 23847 23847 98575 98575 61282 ...
 $ screen_name_mention: Factor w/ 150233 levels "","#$%","#cuttingeeg",..: 41276 110025 110025 33531 15579 17454 61209 112371 38473 110091 ...
 $ USER_LINK          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Example:

```
 User_name  M_User  Total
   user 1  user 2     7
   user 1  user 3    19
   user 1  user 7     5
   user 3  user 2     1
   user 2  user 7     1
```

End Results

```
User_name user 1 user 2 user 3 user 7
   user 1      0      7     19      5
   user 2      0      0      0      1
   user 3      0      1      0      0
   user 7      0      0      0      0
```

My code works fine for small dataset like this (even creates 5000x5000 matrix) but not for large dataset

Comment: Please share `head` of your data.

Comment: added in question now @MKR

Comment: Thanks @melissa. Could you please share `str` of your data as well?

Comment: sure added in question @MKR

Comment: Do you want to obtain an array from your data?

Comment: @Onyambu i have updated the question with an example of what I need

Comment: you adjacency matrix will be large (150233*150233), so try setting `sparse=TRUE` in `xtabs` to see if it helps. Or create a graph using `igraph` and output a sparse adj matrix??

Comment: can you give a try to `reshape2::dcast(df,User_name~M_user,fill = 0)`?

Comment: can't convert a sparse matrix to normal matrix it gives error @user20650

Comment: @Onyambu It does't detect USER_LINK for some odd reasons, there are no spelling mistakes :/ it gives the error `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'USER_LINK' not found`

Comment: @melissa ; are you trying to convert the sparse matrix to a dense matrix using all the data? if so, why? The reason to use a sparse matrix is so that it uses much much less memory. A 150233*150233 matrix is very unlikely to fit in memory (150233*150233*8/2^30 = 168GB), but you adjacency matrix is 99.99% sparse (100 * (1 - 512218 / (150233*150233))). It wastes space to explicitly store the zeros, so the sparse matrix representation only stores the non-zero elements - hence it fits in memory

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `spread` function from `tidyr` package.

If you apply `spread` function on the data-set example provided by you:

```
df <- data.frame(User_name = c("user 1", "user 1", "user 1", "user 3", "user 2"),
                 M_user = c("user 2", "user 3", "user 7", "user 2", "user 7"),
                 Total = c(7, 19, 5, 1, 1)
                 )

>df
User_name  M_User  Total
user 1  user 2     7
user 1  user 3    19
user 1  user 7     5
user 3  user 2     1

#spread will convert the data as below:
> spread(df, M_user, Total)
  User_name user 2 user 3 user 7
1    user 1      7     19      5
2    user 2     NA     NA      1
3    user 3      1     NA     NA
```

I normally prefer to break `big data` horizontally during analysis to understand nature of data in a better. For example, in OP data is more than 500+ K which is blocking any analysis. I would prefer to break data into, say, 5 parts as:

```
df[1:100000,]
df[100001:200000,]
df[200001:300000,]
df[300001:400000,]
df[400001:512218,]
```

Analyse those 5 subsets (one can break those in even smaller sets) first, that may give you a better understanding of data to apply rules. It is also possible that one can think of analyzing smaller sets first and then finding an easy way to combine the results.